# Cage for Parakeets

Tags: safety, birds, cage, budgerigar

We've recently added two parakeets to our family. I've been doing tons of reading and research, but I still have much more to do.

Based on my research I've determined that the cage that the pet shop sold me is too small to keep our budgies happy (but perfect for vet visits).

I love the build quality and size of the cage below, but the site doesn't list budgies in the "built for [insert types of birds here]" information.

Are there any experienced parakeet owners that could tell me if this is a good cage for our two new parakeets?

[Here's the page in the original Spanish (we're living in Spain).](http://www.pajareras.es/jaulas-y-voladeros/jaulas-para-loros/jaula-amazonas)

[They also have an English version of the page, but it has less information.](http://www.pajareras.es/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=674_682&products_id=2796)

Lastly, [here's a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiEP-vB7fNU) that shows some nice close-ups of the cage.

Comment: I can say that if you're going to spend a bunch of  money like that, you'd might as well have convenient access to the food/water dishes and bottom tray. This cage DOES have those, it's in the video on the product page.

Comment: @rlb.usa, thanks. The food/water/tray combo is my favorite part of the cage. The truth is, it's really bigger and more expensive than I want, but I love the food/water/tray combo, and the metal catch-tray (for lack of a better term). However, as you mentioned, it's expensive. Do you have another suggestion? The food/water/tray on the standard pet store cage I have is awful, and makes me want to hurt myself :-)

Comment: I don't know very many limited budget people who would buy a brand new cage; many folks will buy one used locally. It looks like there is a Craigslist for Spain, but I am not sure if it covers your specific area. If you are handy with tools, theoretically, you could make your own. It may not be as fancy, but it can be bigger/cheaper. Just throwing out some options, because petstores here can be price-gougers as well as yours sounds like.

Comment: It may even be possible to have a metal worker/welder build a metal cage for far cheaper than the one he is considering buying (the home building materials store sells meshed wire sheets already premade). When cost is an issue, all options are good!

Answer (score 3):

James,

A few things to keep in mind...

Cage bar spacing for standard budgies (parakeets) or English budgies should not be greater than 1/2 inch (12.7 mm), or they can get their heads stuck between the cage bars. Some budgies are quite small, and cage bar spacing of 3/8 inch (9.5 mm) is necessary. The cage you're looking at is lovely, but it is designed for larger birds.

Length is more important than height. I use 18 inch wide x 18 high x 30 long (46 x 46 x 76 cm). Excess vertical space will go unused--your birds will just use the upper area almost all of the time. As a minimum, they need to be able to stretch their wings fully and to flutter from perch to perch.

Be sure that there is a tray on the bottom that is easy to remove for cleaning. It is best if there is a grate on the bottom of the cage so that droppings can fall through onto the substrate where the birds can't step in them. (Newspaper as a substrate works fine--don't waste money on expensive cage liners.)

I use green fine mesh shade cloth that I get at my local hardware store around the sides and back. It makes the birds feel more secure and less exposed, and it prevents most seed husks from flying out of the cage.

Easy access to food and water trays is helpful. Avoid plastic trays--they harbor bacteria. If necessary, I'd rather use ceramic dishes accessed through the main door than to use plastic trays accessed through small side doors. Keep food and water apart, and don't let either be under perches (poop prevention). Remember that budgies love to bathe, so a wide, shallow dish of water is appreciated. A third dish for greens and veggies (lettuce, shredded carrots, lima beans, etc.--NO avocado or onions, as they are poisonous to birds) is a good idea.

A variety of perch sizes and shapes will help your budgies keep their leg muscles and tendons in good shape. My budgies love their swing, too.

I hope this helps. Enjoy your new family members!

Tom

Answer (score 1):

[image: Hagen Vision Cage]

I recommend the Hagen Vision cage (photo). I originally bought one cage, in the medium size (about 60x60x40 cm), which is big enough for a pair of budgies. But my female bird is bossy and she bullies the male so I bought a second one to give them each their own bedroom - my birds only sleep in their cages and spend all day out and about (I work from home so I can give them this freedom).

The Hagen design is very practical, easy to clean, plenty of doors to access the interior. I did not like the perches supplied with the cage so fitted new ones made of rope and natural wood. I use a variety of food/water containers and cage toys to keep the cage interesting but I only change things gradually so that the birds are not upset.

I live in England. The Hagen Vision cages cost about £75 each. The extra equipment (perches, food bowls, toys, food, treats etc) cost about £75 per cage. I estimate that each cage set-up was about £150. I think this is a reasonable amount to invest in essential petcare. It's about the same cost as a cage for a guinea pig, hamster etc and a lot cheaper than the cost of an aquarium for pet fish, vivarium for reptiles or the costs associated with keeping a pet cat or dog.

Answer (score 0):

That cage seems plenty big for two budgies. They are small birds and especially if they are tame and you handle them frequently, you won't need a huge cage. However, it's better to have horizontal bars verses vertical ones, so that your birdies can climb on the cage without slipping down.

Just place lots of perches and toys in the cage and they should be fine.  The photo I've attached is of my budgie's cage, her toys are removed though so I could clean them. As you can see a budgie does not need a massive cage, mine doesn't have a huge cage and she is still a very happy bird.

[image]